# Firebase RSS feed for SDK changes

Tags: firebase

Thanks for example this change log https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Is there a way to be notified then something is added?

Comment: There is no built-in RSS/ATOM feed on that page, but there are tons of online tools that turn reasonably structured HTML into RSS. I'd recommend searching for those.